# Remove field from user profile in alfresco community

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-maven

I am using alfresco community 5.0.d

I want to remove google username field from the user profile.

So far,
I found the file that handles this form, userprofile.get.html.ftl and userprofile.get.js. Now as I comment out the div tag for google username field in userprofile.get.html.ftl then the whole form is getting hidden without any error on console.

Form is coming blank as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

Any idea how to remove?

Thanks.

Comment: Even I'm getting similar behaviour in Alfresco Enterprie 5.0.2 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for form not being displayed was that I was just removing the div tags but not the dom.get method for those fields.

*Files to be modified:*

- profile.js
- userprofile.get.html.ftl

*Solution:*

- Remove the dom.get for the fields that you want to remove from
  profile.js.
- Remove the div tags of those fields from the
  userprofile.get.html.ftl.
- Restart the tomcat

Voilaaaa !!!

Fixed and Done.

Answer (score 1):

I added `hidden` class to the `div` to hide them instead of removing it,as it is not displaying any of the form fields as you mentioned.

```
<#if profile.googleUsername?? && profile.googleUsername?length!=0>
               <div class="row hidden">
                  <span class="fieldlabelright">${msg("label.googleusername")}:</span>
                  <span class="fieldvalue">${profile.googleUsername?html}</span>
               </div>
               </#if>
```

And for the Edit fields,

```
<div class="row hidden">
               <span class="label"><label for="${el}-input-googleusername">${msg("label.googleusername")}:</label></span>
               <span><input type="text" maxlength="256" size="30" id="${el}-input-googleusername" value="" <@immutablefield field="googleusername" /> /></span>
            </div>
```

[image: User Profile Page]

[image: User Profile Edit Page]

And it is working fine.

Comment: I have fixed the issue and its working like a charm. Please see my answer.